# Find Number of Instances Within GroupBy ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an application that shows a list of errors. Previously it showed every single error within the database but I have now put a GroupBy on it to group all the recurring errors together.

It now only shows the `FirstOrDefault()` for each group by but I am wanting to have column that states how many times each error has occurred.

[image]

As you can see from the image above, this is the output I currently have. If you take the top record, for example, /LM/W3SVC/7/ROOT has 13 instances of the same error. What I am wanting to do is add another column that shows how many times each error has occurred, which in this case, would be 13.

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Errors(string sortOrder, int? page)
   {
       ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
       ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

       var queryString = RouteData.Values["id"];

       var applications = db.ElmahErrors.Where(s => s.Application.Replace("/", "").Replace(".", "") == queryString)
                   .GroupBy(s => s.Type)
                   .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault());

       switch (sortOrder)
       {
           default:
               applications = applications.OrderByDescending(s => s.TimeUtc);
               break;
       }
        int pageSize = Int32.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPageSize"]);            
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

       return View(applications.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

#### View

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<DataIntelligence.Models.ElmahError>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Application Error Dashboard";
}
<script>
    function goBack() {
        window.history.back();
    }
</script>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Application Error Dashboard</h2>
</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Application
        </th>
        <th>
            Host
        </th>
        <th>
            Type
        </th>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id=item.ErrorId})"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ErrorId) </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Application)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Host)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeUtc)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Errors", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))

<a href="#" onclick="goBack()" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
    Back
</a>
```

What would I need to add to my Controller code in order to make this possible? And how would I then go on to display that value in my view?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548534/how-to-count-group-by-rows-in-t-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Count` here:-

```
var applications = db.ElmahErrors.Where(s => s.Application.Replace("/", "")
                                                      .Replace(".", "") == queryString)
                   .GroupBy(s => s.Type)
                   .Select(grp => new
                            {
                                 ErrorCount = grp.Count(),
                                 ErrorObj = grp.FirstOrDefault()
                            });
```

Please note, here I am projecting an anonymous type but since you need to bind it to a View, you need to define a `Model` with a property say ErrorCount, which can act as your column in View.

So suppose you define a class like this:-

```
    public class ErrorCountModel
    {
        public int ErrorCount { get; set; }
        public ElmahError ElmahError { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can project this model instead of anonymous type like this:-

```
 .Select(grp => new ErrorCountModel
               {
                  ErrorCount = grp.Count(),
                  ElmahError = grp.FirstOrDefault()
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a property on your model to hold the count, so for example if you are happy displaying the first record and the count you could do this.

```
public class EmahErrorCount
{
    public EmahError Error { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Then you query would look like

```
var applications = db.ElmahErrors.Where(s => s.Application.Replace("/", "").Replace(".", "") == queryString)
                   .GroupBy(s => s.Type)
                   .Select(grp => new EmahErrorCount()
                            {
                                 Count = grp.Count(),
                                 Error = grp.FirstOrDefault()
                            });
```

You would also have to update your view accordingly.